# Form Not Passing Post to php

Tags: php

Well this is strange but my form is not passing POST data.

Here is the form

```
<form method="POST" action="process/processor.php">
<input name="name3" type="text">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Here is the PHP

```
<?php    
if(isset($_POST['submit']) AND $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){   

$name = $_POST['name3'];

echo $name;

}
else{
    echo 'lol';
}

?>
```

Here is where it gets surprising

`var_dump($_POST)` gives `array(0) { }` on the other hand, `var_dump($_GET)` gives `rray(2) { ["name3"]=> string(6) "fghjmk" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" }`

It looks like i'm getting data with `GET`and no data with `POST`. This is quite strange to me. Any suggestions?

And nothing is echoed out for variable `$name`

Comment: Use === equals. if(isset($_POST['submit']) AND $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST"){

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943060/isset-postsubmit-vs-serverrequest-method-post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [isset($\_POST\['submit'\]) vs $\_SERVER\['REQUEST\_METHOD'\]=='POST'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943060/isset-postsubmit-vs-serverrequest-method-post)

Comment: @Hizqeel I tried using either but still didn't get the results I expected

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST" action="process/processor.php">
<input name="name3" type="text">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

instead of <input type="submit" name="submit">, use <input type="submit" name="submit" value='submit'>

the $_POST['submit'] might be empty using <input type="submit" name="submit">. so, i think is not getting into the block code.
```